# How to set linker flags for main executable

Tags: lua, linker, flags, luajit

My dynamic library uses LuaJIT which requires setting the following flags to build 64bit macOS application.

```
-pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000
```

However, if I add these flags on my Xcode project and build it, I get the following error.

```
ld: -pagezero_size option can only be used when linking a main executable
```

I guess it's because I'm building a dynamic library and not an executable which is the host program that loads the library.

Is it possible to set these flags for my host program which is already built as a binary?

Comment: This really depends on your compiler.  If you are using GCC add `-Wl,-pagezero_size,10000,-image_base,100000000` to the compiler flags.  If you are using a build system, there is probably a variable `LDFLAGS` which you could set.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I added the flags in "Other Linker Flags" on Xcode which works when I build the project as an executable but I'm building my project as a dynamic Library.(.dylib) I think this is why I get the error and I would like to know if there's any work around.

Comment: Oh, I have no idea whether you can configure the dynamic linker in any way.  The only thing I can think of is browsing the man page for info: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld